# How to reset the computer to ask for user account control prompt after msi installation

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have to install SQL Server Native client using PowerShell.

When i use the below command to install the same it comes up with a user account control prompt :

```
$arguments = "/i C:\Users\Subhayan\Desktop\sqlncli_32.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /passive IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES"
start-process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList $arguments
```

So i searched some blogs and came up with a solution that i have to enable the registry key value : AlwaysInstallElevated in the path : HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer

This key was not present so i created that and set the value to 1 .The installation went through properly.

But since this is a production system i have to toggle it back to what it was original . So i again made the registry key value to 0 :

```
PSPath                : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Inst
                        aller
PSParentPath          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
PSChildName           : Installer
PSDrive               : HKLM
PSProvider            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
AlwaysInstallElevated : 0
```

But when i try to install again to test whether the value has been reset or not , the user account control prompt does not come back. The installation goes on silently.

Can someone please help me how to bring this back ?

Comment: Pass -Credential $cred arg to start-process and not worry about registry?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Local Security Policy editor.
2. In the left pane, expand Local Policies, and click/tap on Security Options. (see screenshot below)
3. In the right pane of Security Options, double click/tap on User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for standard users. (see screenshot above)
4. Select the behavior you want for the UAC elevation prompt for standard users, and click/tap on OK. (see screenshot below)
   NOTE: The default setting is Prompt for credentials. See the blue note box at the top of the tutorial for a description of each setting.
5. Close the Local Security Policy editor.

Comment: Yes but is it possible to do this programmatically , i mean in PowerShell? In the prod environment all this should be done using a single script .